# Symfony Omines Datatables column filtering not working

Tags: symfony4

I use Omines Datatables bundle, it's working fine.

However, I have a problem for column filtering. I use it usually with basic datatables in js and server side it's work fine but with omines in syfmony it is not.

```
$('#AdvertsListe').initDataTables(routes.datatable_settings, {
        "dom": "Blfrtip",
        'searching' : true,
       "bFilter": true,
        'ordering' : true,
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": 0,
                "width": "8%"
            },
            {
                "targets": 0,
                "width": "8%"
            }

        ]
    }).then(function(dt) {
        // dt contains the initialized instance of DataTables
        dt.on('init', function() {
            $('.column_filter').on('change', function (e) {
                let index = $(this).data('column');
                let searchStr = $(this).val();
                if ($(this).val() != ''){
                    dt.column(index).search(searchStr).draw();
                }

                e.stopPropagation();
                return false;
            });
        })
    });
```

Search parameters are sent in the query but they are ignored and all results returned every time.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?